# I want to add multiple paths in one route as both login and signup goes to AuthIndex component In authindex comp not able to togle b/w login nd signup

Tags: reactjs

How to add multiple paths in one route.
I am not able to get the params type.

```
import Products from "./Components/Products/Products";
import Header from "./Components/Layout/Header";
import Subheader from "./Components/Layout/Subheader";
import {Routes , Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthIndex from "./Components/Auth";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Subheader/>
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route  path = "/login" exact element={<AuthIndex/>}>
        </Route>
        <Route  path = "/signup" exact element={<AuthIndex/>}>
        </Route> */}
        <Route  path = "/:type(login|signup)" 
        exact element={<AuthIndex/>}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/404" element={<h1>Not Found..!!</h1>}>
          </Route>
        <Route path="/:category?" element={<Products/>}>
        </Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
//bug
//third route still to be added navigate route instead of redirect route.
```

I want to toggle between login and signup and show buttons accoriding
and if signup then use the REST api call accorging to the params type.
I want if someone signup then it should be store in my firebase
I also want to know how to get params type.

```
import { NavLink, useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const AuthIndex = () => {
    const [details, setDetails] = useState({
        email : "",
        password: ""
    })
    const params = useParams()

    const handleInput = e => {
        setDetails({
            ...details,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    const handleSubmission = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(details)
        if (params.type === "signup") {
            signupWithEmailAndPassword();
        }
    }


    const signupWithEmailAndPassword = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.post(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyAJNV9-dm4p8t2gYRohFj6jqzPVBgish_A`, {
            email : details.email,
            password : details.password,
            returnSecureToken : true
        })
        console.log(response)
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error.response)
        }
    }

    // console.log(params)
    return (
        <div className="auth-container">
            <div className="auth-container--box">
                <div className="tab-selector">
                    <NavLink  to={"/login"}><h3>Login</h3></NavLink>
                    <NavLink  to={"/signup"}><h3>Signup</h3></NavLink>
                </div>
                <form  autoComplete={"off"} onSubmit={handleSubmission}>
                    <div className="input-wrap">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" 
                            name="email" 
                            placeholder="Enter Email" 
                            value={details.email} 
                            onChange={handleInput}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-wrap">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input 
                            type="password" 
                            name="password" 
                            placeholder="Enter Password"
                            value={details.password}
                            onChange={handleInput}
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div className="button-wrap">
                        <button className="login-btn">
                            {/* but to solve , showing signup in both cases */}
                            {params.type === "login" ? "Login" : "Signup"}
                            {/* Login */}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AuthIndex
```

Comment: Instead of this logic, you can create two separate routes for login and signup and pass a prop to AuthIndex component like isLogin. Based on isLogin prop you can differentiate between login and signup in AuthIndex.

Comment: The easy way just check the javascript native History API and when you navigate you can push and pop state as needed or you could
try wrapping your AuthIndex by means of a Context/Provider Pattern using a global store that saves your state or create a custom hook i.e: useAuth that returns the type needed instead of `"/:type(login|signup)" ` on the path prop